# Rails hstore value based query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I want to query an hStore column on PG database and return ONLY the values corresponding to a specific key and value.
hstore column contains the information in the below manner

```
hours: {"tue_1_open"=>"19:30", "tue_1_close"=>"21:45"}
```

I am able to query based on key and value as follows

```
Model.where("hours @> hstore(:key,:value )", key: "tue_1_open", value: "19:30")
```

But I want to query whose value is grater than specific time. I want query something like

```
Model.where("hours @> hstore(:key,:value )", key: "tue_1_open", value: ">= 19:30")
```

Any idea how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get greater value in integer not time

```
Model.where("(hours ? 'tue_1_open')::int > 19")
```

for datetime hours value of  `'tue_1_open'` should be a Datetime value

```
Model.where("(hours ? 'tue_1_open')::timestamp > Time.now")
```

Comment: I am getting 
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "datetime" does not exist

Comment: Perhaps you mean `timestamp` instead of `datetime`.

Comment: I tried both but I am getting 
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type boolean to time without time zone